# Evolution will not connect with gmail. Errors are "Failed to authenticate: timeout was reached" and "password not available"

Tags: password, email, authentication, gmail, imap

I am trying to use the Evolution mail client and it is not connecting to Gmail.  This used to work, I have thousands of messages in evolution.
I am using the server imap.gmail.com, port 993.  I have encryption set to TLS on a dedicated port.  Check for supported types.  I have tried checking for supported types, and only password and Oath2 are allowed (all other types are struck through).  I've tried both.  Oauth2 times out, and if I use a password, then I pass all of the passwords, recognizing deformed characters and testing my cellphone.  I know this because if I enter an incorrect value, I get immediate feedback that the value is wrong.  I even get messages from Google telling me that somebody is logging in to my account.  But I get "password not available" error messages from Evolution.
I am using Evolution 3.44.4-0ubuntu2, LxQT 0.17.0, Qt 5.15.3, Ubuntu 22.04.3LTS.
If I use Google's web-based Gmail account, then that works fine.  I'm using that as a workaround, so my troubles are annoying, and not stopping.
I have gone to several websites, and either they assume that there is a high level of abstraction and do not specify port #, protocol, authentication method, or encryption method, or else they give the values I am using.

What's really frustrating is that this worked until a couple of days ago.

Thank you, people, whoever you are, wherever you are.

Comment: Same issue here - was working with Ubuntu 20.04 / Evolution.
Now upgraded to Ubuntu23 / Evolution 3.50.0-1 and cannot connect to gmail-accounts. Evolution is asking 2 times for the password via the gmail-interface connection to confirm the password - this login works successfully.
But when trying to retrieve mail from the server, the login fails. Any update on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my issue:
The authentication method for the Gmail account was not properly set.
I had to manually set it from "Password" to "OAuth2" in the Edit-->Accounts-->Mailbox settings for both receive and send.

Now the authentication works properly.